# Probability: $A,B,C\subseteq \Omega$ (where $\Omega$ is the probability space.) If $ A \subseteq B$, Prove or disprove $P(A) \le P(A\mid B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A,B,C are three events in our probability space

Two questions:

1.) $A,B,C\subseteq \Omega$ (where $\Omega$  is the probability space.) If $ A \subseteq B$, Prove or disprove $P(A) \le  P(A\mid B)$

2.)  $A,B,C\subseteq \Omega$ (where $\Omega$  is the probability space.) If $ B \subseteq A$, Prove or disprove $P(A) \le  P(A\mid B)$

This is my train of thought:

1.) If A is a subset of B, then at most A will be equal to B (is this correct?) or smaller than B. Let's assume that A is equal to B, then we have (where P is the probability):

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} $$

Now because A at most the space probability as B, then $P(A \cap B) =0$ (Is this correct as well?) and we get that it's false.

Question two is very similar to question one, so if my though process is correct then I should be able to handle it.

I appreciate any help as my foundations for statistics and probability are quite shaky.

Comment: You wrote the wrong formula: $P(A\mid B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, which makes the problem way easier.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need $C$ for?

Comment: If $A\subseteq B$ then $A\cap B=A$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks! had it right in my work. C is used for other questions. Not really necessary for these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $P(A | B) = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

If $A \subseteq B$, what does the above formula reduce to?  If $B \subseteq A$, what does the above formula reduce to?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not really sure. Can I assume if $ A \subset B $  then P(A) = P(B)?

Comment: @RonaldB: If $A\subset B$ then $A\cap B=A$.

Comment: @T.Eskin would it make a difference if $A \subseteq B$?

Comment: @RonaldB. Nope. Still the same. Maybe it's a good exercise for you to convince yourself of this by proving the statement. Assume that $A\subseteq B$ and prove that $A\cap B\subset A$ and $A\cap B\supset A$

Comment: @RonaldB If $A \subseteq B$, then that means every element in $A$ is in $B$.  So when we look at the set of elements that are common to $A$ and $B$, which is denoted as $A \cap B$, this turns out to be all of $A$.  Similarly, if $B \subseteq A$, then $B \cap A=  B$ by the same reasoning.

Comment: @user46944 How would I complete the proof. I have:

$P(A) \le \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$.

 What exactly does this tell me? Am I to cancel out P(A) on each side, and have P(A)  $\le$ 1? Or is $P(A) \le \frac{P(B)}{P(B)}$ enough?

EDIT Bear with me, formattting is proving to be difficult for me today

Comment: @RonaldB It looks like you're talking about the case where $A \subseteq B$.  Remember that $P(B) \leq 1$.  Now, if you have a number $c$, and you divide it by a number $r$ with $0 < r < 1$, what can we say about $c/r$?  It's bigger than $c$.  Here are some examples: $5 / .1 = 50$, and $50$ is bigger than $5$.  Another example: $9/.75 = 12$, and $12$ is bigger than $9$.

Comment: @RonaldB Using this idea, since $P(B) \leq 1$, $\dfrac{P(A)}{P(B)} \geq P(A)$.  But the left hand side equals $P(A | B)$ if $A \subseteq B$, so we get that $P(A |B) \geq P(A)$ and we are done.